# PHP Array with One Element but unknown index. How to get?

Tags: php, arrays

A function is returning arrays which look like

```
( [4] => SomeObject )
```

or

```
( [2] => SomeObject )
```

If I know the array will always have only one child how can I access it without knowing the index?

I'm sure PHP has an equivalent to Javascript's `getOwnPropertynames`, but I would think there must be a more direct way.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something ? Or did some research ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `current`:

```
$value = current($arr);
```

`current` returns the value of the element currently pointed to by the array's internal pointer. In this case, that will be the first (and only) element of the array.

Testing it out:

```
function f() {
    return array(4 => 'foo');
}

$arr = f();
echo current($arr);
```

Output:

```
foo
```